# Spring boot application returning the string name of the JSP rather than the JSP itself

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a web app using Spring boot.

The use case is, if an user goes to home page, he will be redirected to a new unique URL each time. Eg: www.Qqd.com --> www.qqd.com\jsdh. 
Next time it would be something different, like www.qqd.com\dkjfbd

But in both the cases, it will show same JSP. 
I am doing it as a REST framework so that in future I can extend for mobile app development as well.

[image]

```
package com.example.qqd;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class QDetailsService {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(QDetailsService.class);

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView getNewUrl(ModelMap model){
       log.info("URL generated is: ");
       return new ModelAndView("redirect:/"+"abcde", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{url}")
    public String addDetails(@PathVariable String url){
        log.info("URL: " + url + " , detail: " );
        //return new ModelAndView("home.jsp");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

ServletInitializer.java

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(QqdApplication.class);
    }
}
```

QqdApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication //This annotation means, it is the starting point of the app. 
public class QqdApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QqdApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the `@RestController` annotation. It should be `@Controller`. RestController has @ResponseBody annotation which makes it bind responses to the body, rather than resolving a view.

Comment: If I use @Controller, should the addDetails( ) return String or ModelAndView() ?

Comment: you can use either String or ModelAndView. Whatever you like.

Comment: I tried both and I get 



There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/Qqd/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Comment: It's because your `@RequestMapping(value="/{url}")` mapping is catching basically all URLS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning the ModelAndView object? Notice that I removed the .jsp from home.jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{url}")
public ModelAndView addDetails(@PathVariable String url){
    log.info("URL: " + url + " , detail: " );
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I get this error : 
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/Qqd/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Comment: I don't have any resolver like web.xml or anything. All I have is pom.xml. Before Spring boot, in usual Spring MVC I use to configure in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I myself found the solution and following did work
Step1: Have the following lines in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Step 2: I don't see Spring tool suite creating `WEB-INF/jsp` folders under `src/webapp`. So create it and move the jsp under that folder.

This worked like a charm. Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big issue i almost spent more than 2 hour but finally able to resolve.

Step 1 : add to application.properties :-

```
     - spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
     - spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Step 2 : add to pom.xml : -

```
     -dependency 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

Controller

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/homepage",method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public String hello(Model model)
            {
                model.addAttribute("message","Hello");
                return "myjsppage";
            }
```